# How to update PropertyGrid from a custom editor?

Tags: .net, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I'm using the `PropertyGrid` (in the CollectionEditor) to edit some properties of a class. The properties are actually wrapped in classes that implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. One of them uses a custom editor that inherits from `UITypeEditor`. When the user changes the value of this property in the custom editor, the value of another property is also being updated (by code in the custom editor; the property wrapper has a reference to the other property for this reason). So far so good.

But when the user closes the custom editor, the `PropertyGrid` only shows the new value of the edited property and does not refresh the other property (even though its value has definitely changed).

How can I refresh the entire containing `PropertyGrid` from the custom editor?

Comment: Use the [RefreshProperties] attribute on the property you edit.

Comment: @HansPassant It doesn't work. I've tried <RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)> on all properties and also returning this through the PropertyDescriptor inheritor. Perhaps this is because the PropertyGrid I'm using is actually the one inside the CollectionEditor?

Comment: Somebody broke my crystal ball this morning, I'll be out of one for the rest of the year.  Clearly you'll need to do a much better job documenting your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

The EditValue method of the custom editor should return a new object, not the passed in value object. Then the PropertyGrid automatically refreshes the other properties as well.

I did not need to use the RefreshProperties attribute anywhere.